# GWT Java calculate days between two dates on the server side

Tags: java, gwt, server-side

I am using GWT java. I have a report on the client side that I want to export to csv. So I am trying to create the report on the server side to pass back to the client side as a csv file so the user can store the csv file in their selected destination.

The following code works on the client side; however, does not work on the server side (i.e., "Print 6." is displayed and "Print 7." is not displayed on the server side). There is no error message. The dates are "2016-11-09" and "2000-02-02".

```
        System.out.println(todays_date);
        System.out.println(pack.getDob());
        System.out.println("Print 6.");

        float diffDOB = (CalendarUtil.getDaysBetween(pack.getDob(), todays_date));
        System.out.println("Print 7.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was talking about this with a fiend, who is not a programmer, and she said why not just send the MS Excel formula. Brilliant! So I have removed all the calclations and am now sending:

```
           fileContent.append(pack.getSurname() + "," + pack.getFirstname() + "," + pack.getScout_no() + "," +
                pack.getgroup() + "," + pack.getDob() + "," + '"' + "=ROUNDDOWN(((TODAY()-E"+row+")/365),1)" + '"' + "," +
                pack.getstartDate() + "," + '"' + "=ROUNDDOWN(((TODAY()-G"+row+")/365),1)" + '"' + "," +
                '"' + "=EDATE(E"+row+",216)" + '"' + "\n");
```

The only issue now is that spaces in the string fields appear as + in the output file.